# Windows Installer

Tags: windows-installer

I have stuck in a very simple problem, I am using Windws instaler to deploy my project.
In that I have used a custom dialog [TextBoxes(A)] for User name and Passowrd.

Now what I am trying is two things
first to Enable Next button on the dialog only if user enters both values i.e. Usename and Pwd and second as user click Next followed by filling both fields a validation should occue(I have code ready in c# for validation!), I validate user can go to next dialog in Installer.

I tried some stuffs with Orca but I didnt succed, please help me in providing the solution.

Comment: Please add information about what, *exactly*, you have tried and how, *exactly*, it has failed. "I tried some stuffs" doesn't give us any information with which we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more information on the exact nature of your problem could be helpful.  I assume you are talking about the free installer project included with VS.

You will need to make custom installer entry points.  I assume that this is what you were trying with the c# code.  I know of only making these in c++, but I seem to recall that you can do this also with c#.

For debugging the custom entry points, you can write to a log file or, as a last resort, put up message boxes.

Orca can be quite handy, but time wise, if you want to do something complex, you will probably be better off, shelling out some $$ for a more deluxe installer package.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with editing ControlCondition table with orca and can enable/disable next button! but now what I am looking is to call a c# function on next click to validate username/pwd.